# Both error and success callbacks in the same write

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, html5-filesystem

When saving files using a `FileWriter`, the error and success callbacks fire both. This only happens on certain android devices (v4.3 & v5) while working on others. The plugin version is 2.0.0

The `FileError` has code 6 which is "NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR".

Here some code:

```
this.cwd.getFile(id, {create: true}, function(file) {
    file.createWriter(function(writer) {

        writer.onerror = fail;

        writer.onwriteend = function() {
            success(id, file.toURL());
        };

        writer.write(blob);

    }, fail);
}, fail);
```

Bug in the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh damn! Plugin v2.1 is available and solves the issue...